# I'm doing a Discord bot, and having trouble connecting bot to voice channel, any suggestions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js, bots

I want to import joinVoiceChannel from discordjs/voice, but it says

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

That's because I'm using .cjs file, if I'm using .js file then nothing will work.

Can anybody help me how to connect DiscordBot to voice channel, I can ping him but can not connect him.

main.js

```js
import DiscordJS, { Intents } from 'discord.js'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import { createRequire } from "module";

dotenv.config()

const client = new DiscordJS.Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
    ]
})

const prefix = '!';

const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new DiscordJS.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.cjs'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Mariachi is online!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'ping') {
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command === 'play') {
        client.commands.get('play').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command === 'leave') {
        client.commands.get('leave').execute(message, args);
    }
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

play.cjs

```js
import { joinVoiceChannel } from "@discordjs/voice";
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');

module.exports = {    

    name: 'play',
    description: 'Joins and plays a video from youtube',
    async execute(message, args) {              

        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
 
        if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissions');
        if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissions');
        if (!args.length) return message.channel.send('You need to send the second argument!');
 
        const validURL = (str) =>{
            var regex = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?/;
            if(!regex.test(str)){
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
 
        if(validURL(args[0])){
 
            const  connection = await joinVoiceChannel.join();
            const stream  = ytdl(args[0], {filter: 'audioonly'});
 
            connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
            .on('finish', () =>{
                voiceChannel.leave();
                message.channel.send('leaving channel');
            });
 
            await message.reply(`:thumbsup: Now Playing ***Your Link!***`)
 
            return
        }
 
        
        const  connection = await joinVoiceChannel.join();
 
        const videoFinder = async (query) => {
            const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);
 
            return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
 
        }
 
        const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));
 
        if(video){
            const stream  = ytdl(video.url, {filter: 'audioonly'});
            connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
            .on('finish', () =>{
                voiceChannel.leave();
            });
 
            await message.reply(`:thumbsup: Now Playing ***${video.title}***`)
        } else {
            message.channel.send('No video results found');
        }
    }
}
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "discordbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/opus": "^0.7.0",
    "@discordjs/voice": "github:discordjs/voice",
    "discord.js": "^13.3.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "ffmpeg-static": "^4.4.0",
    "yt-search": "^2.10.2",
    "ytdl-core": "^4.9.1"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

These are the commands I've found on StackOverflow

```js
import { joinVoiceChannel } from "@discordjs/voice";

const connection = joinVoiceChannel(
    {
        channelId: message.member.voice.channel,
        guildId: message.guild.id,
        adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
    });
```

Comment: why are you using both es6 modules and common js modules ?

Comment: That was the only way I could make it to ping myself.

Answer (score 1):

`.cjs` files are CommonJS. These need `require` rather than the `import` keyword

```js
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require("@discordjs/voice")
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core')
const ytSearch = require('yt-search')
```

And since you have `"type": "module"` in package.json, the `.js` files will need the `import` keyword

Comment: I did that now, but now it says that it can't find the module.

Comment: Seems you didn't install it, do `npm install @discordjs/voice`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');
```

use this above your module.exports and it should start working, but i am having a problem with audio after that, it will join the call but not play any audio

my error code is connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1, type: "opus"})
ReferenceError: connection is not defined